# moving the viewpoint of opengl to find objects off screen

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, perspectivecamera

I have an object moving around in my opengl surface and it sometimes goes off the screen so i was wondering how do you change where you are looking in the world so i can find my object as it is moving around.

This is the renderer for my square object

```
class SquareRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

private int counter = 0;
private boolean mTranslucentBackground;
private Square mSquare;
private float mTransY;
private float mTransX;
private float mAngle;
private Context context;

private float xPoint = 0.0f;
private float yPoint = 0.0f;


public SquareRenderer(boolean useTranslucentBackground,Context context) {
    mTranslucentBackground = useTranslucentBackground;
    this.context=context;
    mSquare = new Square();
}

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glTranslatef(mTransX, mTransY, -10.0f);


    mSquare.draw(gl);
    GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, (float) MainActivity.azimuth, (float) MainActivity.roll, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1, 0.0f);
    Random rnd = new Random();

    float maxx = 180.0f;
    float minx = -180.0f;
    float maxy = 90.0f;
    float miny = -90.0f;

    if( xPoint == 0.0f && yPoint == 0.0f){
        xPoint = rnd.nextFloat()*(maxx-minx)+minx;
        xPoint = round(xPoint,1);
        yPoint = rnd.nextFloat()*(maxy-miny)+miny;
        yPoint = round(yPoint,1);

        Log.d("XPOINT    YPOINT",xPoint +"      " +yPoint);
    }
    if(mTransX != xPoint && xPoint>mTransX) {
        mTransX += 0.1f;
        mTransX = round(mTransX,1);
    }else if(mTransX != xPoint && xPoint<mTransX){
        mTransX -= 0.1f;
        mTransX = round(mTransX,1);
    }else if(mTransX == xPoint){
        xPoint = rnd.nextFloat()*(maxx-minx)+minx;
        xPoint = round(xPoint,1);
    }
    if(mTransY != yPoint && yPoint >mTransY) {
        mTransY += 0.1f;
        mTransY = round(mTransY,1);
    }else if(mTransY != yPoint && yPoint < mTransY){
        mTransY -= 0.1f;
        mTransY = round(mTransY,1);
    }else if(mTransY == yPoint){
        yPoint = rnd.nextFloat()*(maxy-miny)+miny;
        yPoint = round(yPoint,1);
    }
}

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    float ratio = (float) width / height;
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 1, 10);
}

public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    gl.glDisable(GL11.GL_DITHER);
    gl.glHint(GL11.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL11.GL_FASTEST);
    gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
    gl.glEnable(GL11.GL_CULL_FACE);
    gl.glShadeModel(GL11.GL_SMOOTH);
    gl.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What are you even using? 2D, 3D? What kind of projection? Did you check the "look at" matrix? This is defined as the point where you are standing and the point toward which you are looking at. Seems perfect to what you seem to describe.

Comment: i have edited the post to include the code for my object renderer. The object right now is just a 2d square moving around randomly in the world

Comment: Ok, but what is your goal? What should happen when the object runs off the screen? Should you try to do something as paging? Or should the camera always follow the object so the object always appears in the center? Or maybe you wish to do a trail so the camera will follow the object with a delay?

Comment: basically the idea is to find the object as it moving around, so as the user turns and moves the phone the viewpoint changes accordingly in order to find where the object is

Comment: If I now understand correctly what you are looking for is how to fix your gluLookAt parameters. The azimuth and roll are angles and you need to use trigonometry to compute the vector. I think those should be (cos(azimuth)*cos(roll), sin(roll), sin(azimuth)*cos(roll)) but you best check for similar questions or play around with it.